# How to configure webpack to code-split small static react pages

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

I have a react app bundled with webpack. Some of my pages have heavy dependencies, but other pages are static with basic HTML. The only shared dependencies on the static pages are react, react-dom, react-router-dom, and a couple small deps used in the nav header and footer. I am already using react lazy to code-split by route, but the main bundle includes large deps like @material-ui/core, which those static pages don't need.

On their own, those bundles are ~12kb, but the main bundle adds ~1mb to that. These pages have a score of 12-15 on google lighthouse, and I feel like react is supposed to be much faster than that. How can I separate out those static pages so they are bundled small? Also how can I improve my main bundle so it's only including necessary deps on every page.

Comment: Hi Jeremy! It seems you are on the right track, since you found that those smaller bundles around 12kB are individually prepared by webpack. So, I'm inclined to think the issue is not in the webpack configuration. More likely, it's a logical error related to eg. how you modularize components and where you import them. 

Try commenting out parts of your app, everything that webpack treats as if they rely on materia-ui. Start adding them again, one by one, and monitor the bundle size. If you find something unexpected, look deeper and try to isolate the source problem.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. That's a great idea. I'll try debugging that way!